# Problema ao Recuperar GeoLocalização do Usuário

Tags: javascript, geolocalização

Estou tendo problemas ao recuperar a geolocalização do usuário no site. 
Localhost funciona, mas na rede não. Estou achando que o problema é por não ter certificado SSL e o site ser acessado por HTTP e não HTTPS.

Vejam o erro:

> **getCurrentPosition()** and **watchPosition()** are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as **HTTPS**. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

Meu código:

```
if(navigator.geolocation){
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
       var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
       var lng = pos.coords.longitude;

       console.log(lat + ' - ' + lng);
   }
}
```

E no Safari não funciona. Não consegue recuperar a geolocalização pelo Localhost. Nos outros navegadores funciona normalmente no Localhost.

Comment: Sobre o safari, vi que para suportar a geoLocalização, a versão tem que ser 5.0 +.

Comment: Peter Park, vale lembrar que esse tipo de interação com o navegador exige a permissão do usuário final da sua aplicação. Caso contrário todos os seus esforços serão em vão

Comment: Verdade mesmo, @ViniciusDutra ? Puxa... Vida...

Comment: podes sempre usar o https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 1):

### Restrição do Navegador

[Nessa página do w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) você encontra mais detalhes sobre o uso das funções de geolocalização com exemplos. Inclusive tem código para você checar se o navegador tem suporte a essa funcionalidade.

Basicamente existem dois alertas:

> Since this can compromise privacy, the position is not available
>   unless the user approves it.

Sempre que você requisitar no seu código, o usuário receberá uma mensagem para aprovar a requisição.

> As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts
>   such as HTTPS. If your site is hosted on an non-secure origin (such as
>   HTTP) the requests to get the users location will no longer function.

A função só funciona em contexto seguro, como HTTPS. Mesmo funcionando em `localhost` para seus testes, não vai funcionar quando você publicar o site.